# MS Access Table columns mixed when I call them by index number from Java

Tags: java, ms-access

I'm setting up an MS Access db with a table with columns, and when I call them in Java with res.getString(num) they are being mixed.

Let's say I have 3 columns:

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Phone

When I call them on Java, they list like this:

```
res.getString(1) --> last name
res.getString(2) --> phone
res.getString(3) --> first name
```

and when I set a string as last name, it sets as a phone number.

What can I do to list them by the order of the table?

Comment: getString(x) is going to return a column. Not a row. You should show us your entire query. Not just this snippet.

Comment: A row is a record. Lastname, Firstname, Phone should be in columns of a single row (record). So do you really mean column when you say row? Perhaps index begins with 0. Recommend not using spaces in naming convention.

Comment: sorry, as i mentioned, my english is not so well...
turns out, when i said row i actually meant column
sorry again... i'll fix it now